# worklight testing Automation

Tags: unit-testing, ibm-mobilefirst, appium, worklight-mtww

All,

Is there any Unit testing framework that we can use for Worklight apps. I am aware that there is Rational Test Workbench for Mobile([RTWM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/mobile-testing-rational-test-workbench/index.html)) we can use in Worklight IDE for unit testing purpose. I also came across with [Appium.io](http://appium.io/) recently and it looks pretty interesting.

I want to be able to run the automated Unit Tests right after the development of the mobile app. Which one would you prefer or any other tools out in the market?

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 4):

Mobile Test Workbench Worklight (MTWW) is the supported testing framework. Please see: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.mobtest.doc%2Ftopics%2Fc_wl_mobile_test_ovw.html

Comment: I am not sure if we can write scripts for test automation in MTWW. What i mean  is developer can checkin the code to Git or SVN then Jenkin (or any CI) should be able to trigger the automation Unit Testing scripts for the mobile app and send the report if fails.